# apple App store / wp7 marketplace W-8BEN form - is ITIN required if my country has double taxation avoidance treaty wit US?

Tags: app-store, finance, financial

Hi I am about to submit my first paid app for apple's app store and soon wp7 marketplace. The paperwork required to avoid 30% taxation is pretty confusing for me. I am living in the EU.

1) I haven't seen W-8BEN form at itunes connect - do I need to fill it in to avoid 30% tax? - How do I do that?

2) Is ITIN required when submitting W-8BEN to avoi 30% tax if my country has double taxation avoidance treaty signed with the US? I've stumbled upon contradictory statements here... anyone could confirm/deny?

Answer (score 3):

I had to complete a W8-BEN for Microsoft Xbox games, however I couldn't find anything similar in iTunes Connect, so I emailed Apple, and got the following reply:

> Since the App Store contracts are
>   characterized as a "sales/commission"
>   agreement, as opposed to a "royalty"
>   agreement, there is no tax withholding
>   for sales in the USA App Store. In
>   addition, payments from the USA App
>   Store will not be reported to the IRS
>   on form 1042 at year end.

As for the second question, I can't say for sure. I'm in the UK and I *did* obtain an ITIN before completing my W8-BEN.